# Maldives Visa On Arrival, full page or a regular size stamp?

Tags: visas-on-arrival, passport-stamps, maldives

I was wondering, what's the size of the VOA of the Maldives? is it a full page sticker visa, a full page stamp visa or a regular size stamp?

The size of the visa is a game changer in some cases.

Comment: What does VOA stand for?

Comment: @NateEldredge Visa on arrival, changed the tags and the title

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Globetrotter Odyssey](https://globetrotterodyssey.wordpress.com/2012/04/16/maldives-a-thousand-island-paradise/) blog, the visa on arrival is a stamp:

[image: maldives visa on arrival]

Comment: +1. If anyone's wondering the 2015 stamp is the same size, it is (I have a recent stamp on my passport).

Comment: In case anyone's wondering about extending your visa in the Maldives - that results in a half-page size sticker.